# Aspell: how to change home dir globally?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, home, aspell

`aspell` creates following files in my home:

```
.aspell.en.prepl
.aspell.en.pws
```

How can I change the location globally, i.e. to `$HOME/.cache/aspell` ?

I need to reference the `$HOME` environment variables in `/etc/aspell.conf`. I tried the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
home-dir $HOME/.cache/
```

How can I set `home-dir` globally, to be each users `~/.cache` directory ?

**CLARIFICATION**

I don't run `aspell` manually. Applications such as Thunderbird run it themselves. Therefore, using a shell alias is not really a solution.

Comment: It looks like environment variables are not expanded in .aspell.conf, only an hardcoded path such as  `/home/user/.cache` works. What you can do instead is to create a wrapper that would replace `$(command -v aspell)` and would look something like that: `HOME=~/.cache aspell "@$"`

Comment: Or just an alias, if that's enough.

Comment: If you clarified that you don't use `aspell` directly you can still follow my advice and replace aspell with a wrapper.

Comment: Do you ever start the applications that uses `aspell` with a working directory that is anything other than your home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other application do use aspell over library, environnement variables won't work in that case at least not without affecting the main application (Thunderbird or other).

I did patched `aspell` to create a custom version that match this question the repo is [here](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Apps/Aspell) and here is the [patch](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Apps/Aspell/commit/b8e1851305f3c061113e6a1436b075a66ff7467c.patch) to use this custom version you need to uninstall the system's version packages (aspell, libaspell, aspell-[en/fr/etc]) especially **libaspell** you may force the removal of the packages if the dependency are extended to other packages that you don't want to remove. (uninstalling system's packages can be avoided if you setup your environnement variables to use `/use/local` before `/usr` for aspell and libaspell... this may be set by default depending on the used distro)

**Installation:**

```
git clone https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Apps/Aspell.git
cd Aspell
./autogen
./configure
make install
```

Then install the needed dictionary from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html) for instance for the English dictionary you would do:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/aspell6-en-2019.10.06-0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf aspell6-en-2019.10.06-0.tar.bz2
cd aspell6-en-2019.10.06-0/
./configure
make install
```

**Note:**

- There is an issue about this [here](https://github.com/GNUAspell/aspell/issues/560) also there is [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2003-07/msg00002.html) a related discussion.
- The patch in this answer can be implemented with `LD_PRELOAD` by injecting a custom patching library that would change the targeted variable value for the running application... (i would need to implement that custom library... then it would be loaded by setting the env. variable `LD_PRELOAD` for Thunderbird or other app using aspell)... any way as there is already an open issue for the matter this should be fixed mainstream later on.